# Drupal Users permissions and roles

Tags: drupal

Dear friends i'm doing Bsc final for my final year project i have choose Drupal site to build the shopping cards website. I have lots of question to complete my part of the project. unfortunately i could not put my all questions at same page.

How would you grant a particular permission to a particular user?

Comment: pls buy a book on drupal or try drupal irc. This site is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

An individual user or a user role? 
To set user role permissions you need to go to the permissions page under 'people' in the admin menu. Or if you are logged in as admin, just stick this on the end of your url `/users/admin#overlay=admin/people/permissions`